# Same protocol objects, but not the same functions

Tags: swift, design-patterns

I'm trying to build an API pattern.

I have several different APIs that have the same functions for some, and some have additional functions that other APIs do not have and should not have access.

The problem with the protocol is that they all have access. How to limit access if the function is not override?

apiRequest:

```
class APIRequest {
    static func loginCli(completion: (UserClinic) -> ()) {

    }

    static func loginFami(completion: (User) -> ()) {

    }

    static func loginDavid(completion: (UserDavid) -> ()) {

    }
}
```

Protol and API:

```
protocol API {
    func login<T>(completion: (T) -> ())
    func saveClient()
}

extension API {
    func saveClient() {
        saveClient()
    }
}

class FirstAPI: API {
    func login<T>(completion: (T) -> ()) {
        APIRequest.loginFami { (user) in

        }
    }
}

class SecondAPI: API {
    func login<T>(completion: (T) -> ()) {
        APIRequest.loginCli { (user) in

        }
    }
}

class ThreeAPI: API {
    func login<T>(completion: (T) -> ()) {
        APIRequest.loginDavid { (user) in

        }
    }

    func saveClient() {
        // Save client
    }
}
```

View model:

```
class LoginViewModel {
    var apiClient: API

    init() {
        // Below its good
        apiClient = ThreeAPI()
        apiClient.saveClient()

        // Below its not good
        apiClient = FirstAPI()
        apiClient.saveClient() // I want this is not accessible

        // Below its good
        apiClient = SecondAPI()
        apiClient.saveClient() // I want this is not accessible
    }
}
```

In my case I need only the third API to have access to the function `saveClient()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
protocol API {
    func login<T>(completion: (T) -> ())
}

extension API where Self: ThreeAPI {
    func saveClient() {

    }
}
```

In the above code, `protocol API extension` is only available to object of type `ThreeAPI`.

I've used `ThreeAPI` directly here. You can make a `common type` for all the `classes` that need `saveClient()` and use that type in place of `ThreeAPI`

**Usage:**

```
apiClient = ThreeAPI()
(apiClient as? ThreeAPI)?.saveClient()

apiClient = FirstAPI() //saveClient() not available

apiClient = SecondAPI() //saveClient() not available
```

**Edit-1:**

Create a `CommonAPI` parent `class` for all the classes that need `saveClient()` method.

```
class CommonAPI {
    func saveClient() {
        print("CommonAPI saveClient()")
    }
}
```

Inherit `ThreeAPI` and `FourAPI` from `CommonAPI`

```
class ThreeAPI: CommonAPI, API {
    func login<T>(completion: (T) -> ()) {

    }

    override func saveClient() {
        print("ThreeAPI saveClient()")
    }
}

class FourAPI: CommonAPI, API {
    func login<T>(completion: (T) -> ()) {

    }

    override func saveClient() {
        print("FourAPI saveClient()")
    }
}
```

Simply use a `switch statement` to call `saveClient()` on all the objects of type `CommonAPI`.

```
apiClient = FourAPI()
apiClient = ThreeAPI()
apiClient = FirstAPI()
apiClient = SecondAPI()

switch apiClient {
case is CommonAPI:
    (apiClient as? CommonAPI)?.saveClient()

default:
    break
}
```

In this case, you won't need to parse each and every type.

Comment: This does not work because in the viewModel `apiClient` is of type API: Error Value of type 'API' has no member 'saveClient'

Comment: Please look LoginViewModel

Comment: Thank you but that's not what I'm looking for, because if tomorrow I add to the other type of APIClient then I'll have to do a lot of cast, it's not generic

Comment: For making that generic, you can simply create a common type for all the classes that need `saveClient()`.

Comment: Can you explain to me how?

Comment: I've edited the answer. See if you can relate with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the `saveClient` method on `FirstAPI` and `SecondAPI`, you need to extract that method to a separate protocol. Something like:

```
protocol APIThatCanLogin {
    func login<T>(completion: (T) -> ())
}

protocol APIThatCanSave {
    func saveClient()
}


class FirstAPI: APIThatCanLogin { }
class SecondAPI: APIThatCanLogin { }
class ThreeAPI: APIThatCanLogin, APIThatCanSave { }
```

But perhaps you should reconsider using protocols. At least in this example it doesn't offer any benefits.

Comment: This does not work because in the viewModel apiClient is of type API: Error Value of type 'API' has no member 'saveClient

Comment: Please look LoginViewModel

Answer (score 0):

There is not going to be a solution to this as described. The type `API` *means* "has the following methods and properties." You cannot assign something to a variable of type `API` and then say "but it doesn't have some of the methods." That violates [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which is the foundation of these kinds of types. Consider the following code:

```
func save(api: API) {
    api.saveClient()
}
```

If the feature you're describing could be implemented, should this compile or not? If it did compile, and then it were called with `FirstAPI()`, what should happen then?

If you want `saveClient` to be a no-op (to do nothing), then that's very straightforward. Provide an empty default implementation:

```
extension API {
    func saveClient() {}
}
```

If you want some APIs to be savable, and some not to be savable, then that's straightforward too:

```
protocol API {
    func login<T>(completion: (T) -> ())
}

protocol SavableAPI: API {
    func saveClient()
}
```

But the `init` method you've written cannot be made to work. It violates the underlying goal of having a type.